# How to write an output file of multiple time called functions?

Tags: python, function, file-handling

I tried to write a output file from the values return from consecutively called functions but I couldnt make it instead I am getting error like below:

```
    MA.write(l)
TypeError: expected a character buffer object
```

MY script:

```
def do():
    print "Hello"
if __name__ == "__main__":
    do()
    MA=open("hi.txt","w")
    l=map(lambda x: do(), range(10))
    MA.write(l)
```

May be its basic but could someone give suggestions would be really helpful.

Expected OUTPUT:

hi.txt

```
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
```

Thanking you in advance

Comment: `map` does not make sense here, what do you expect the file to contain at the end?

Comment: you could use `MA.writerows()` to write a list of strings to the file but since `do` doesn't return anything it would still raise an error.

Comment: Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
def do():
    return "Hello"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MA=open("hi.txt","w") # Prepare hi.txt
    l=map(lambda x: do(), range(10)) # Adds Hello to the list 10 times
    MA.write('\n'.join(l)) # Combines them together with a newline between each entry
    MA.close() # Finished with hi.txt, this line is important
```

You need to return, not print your output to add it to the list, and then join each list entry into a single string to write with.

Changes I made from your version:

- I return "hello" instead of printing it
- I don't run do() right away,because you don't need to.
- I combine the elements before writing them
- I close the file when I am done

Answer (score 2):

I think this is your intent:

```
def do():
    return "Hello"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with open("hi.txt", "w") as adele:
        hellos = map(lambda x: do(), range(10))
        for hello in hellos:
            adele.write(hello)
```

- `do()` needs to return a value to accumulate in the `map`
- you need to iterate over your `map` result in some way

On the other hand, using the `map` is overkill ... but maybe it makes sense in your larger context.

```
for x in range(10):
    adele.write(do())
```

Comment: Thanks and What do you mean by overkill? do you mean choice of map for large context is bad idea ?

Comment: It's a double abstraction in this context.  You've created a list looping over a range .. then you iterate over that list.  You've looped twice.  You can just loop once. @user3805057